# Create a connection between VB form and Access DB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, vb6

Hi I'm trying to create a front end userform with VB express 2010 I've created a form but want to upload the data I take from textboxes and add it to a recordset in an Access Database.

I've done this using an excel userform and VBA but the consensus is that this isn't a good idea. I just need a nudge on the syntax with visual basic. Here is the code I have the connection sub is my code from VBA. also I'm not sure if I'm using VB6 or VB.Net

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Part As Integer, Job As Integer, Emp As Integer, Weight As Integer, Oven As Integer

        Part = TextBox1.Text
        Job = TextBox2.Text
        Emp = TextBox3.Text
        Weight = TextBox4.Text
        Oven = TextBox5.Text

        Update()
    End Sub

    Sub Update()
        Using cnn = New OleDBConnection (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Persist Security, Info=False;)
            cnn.Open()
            Dim StrSql = "SELECT * FROM Foam WHERE FoamID = ?"
            Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(StrSql, cnn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", )
                Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    If Not reader.HasRows Then
                        reader.Close() ' close because the connection cannot serve a command while reader is open

                        ' no match found; add new record .....USING PARAMETERS.....
                        StrSql = "INSERT INTO Foam VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
                        Using insCmd = New OleDbCommand(SqSql, cnn)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", ID)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Part)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Job)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", Emp)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", Weight)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", Oven)
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End Using
                    Else
                        reader.Close()

                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is my updated code; I can't get New OleDB Connection to work. I think my connection string is alright. This should give a better idea as to the nature of what I want to accomplish.

Comment: If you work with Visual Studio then you have to code for vb.net. You have really mixed a lot of totally different things together

Comment: I assume that the entire Update Sub will be useless. I just wanted to give some context to what I was talking about. At least I now know I'm using VB.net! That will help with google lol. Thanks

Comment: VB6 is Visual Basic 6.0, part of Visual Studio 6.0.  Since you are using "Visual Basic" 2xxx you are using VB.Net (a.k.a. VFred) and not VB6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible answer, but too many details are not clear enough.

First you need a connection string, then you need to create the command that checks the existence of the record, if not found a new command for inserting the values. 
What you want to do when you find the record is not clear enough.

```
Sub Update()
    Using cnn = New OleDbConnection(....a connection string is needed here ....)
        cnn.Open()
        Dim StrSql = "SELECT * FROM Foam WHERE FoamID = ?"
        Using cmd = new OleDbCommand(StrSql, cnn) 
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", F1)
          Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            if Not reader.HasRows
                reader.Close() ' close because the connection cannot serve a command while reader is open

                ' no match found; add new record .....USING PARAMETERS.....
                StrSql = "INSERT INTO Foam VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
                Using insCmd = new OleDbCommand(SqSql, cnn)
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", F1)
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", F2)
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", F3)
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", F4)
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", F5)
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", F6)
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", DateTime.Today)
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", BnWeight)
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            Else
                reader.Close()
                ' matching record found; update it
                ?????? 
            End If
         End Using
      End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I suggest to search the MSDN on an [ADO.NET walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx) because the data access code is substantially different from the ADO model used in VB6 and VBA

Comment: Is there an ADO.NET Walktrough that pertains to Access 2013? I know that JET is no longer relevant, I think.

Comment: Also, that Update Sub was just to give an idea, but essentially I want to Insert a record into a database consisting of the the same fields as the textboxes. Everytime the user hits a submit button the program will append another row to the database.

Comment: The only difference between 2013 and 2003 is just in the provider, otherwise any tutorial on OleDb is equally good.

Comment: Also I understand most of the code, but would the connection string be something like Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"?

Comment: [connectionstrings.com/access2013](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2013/)